# How to get rid of NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql, join, left-join, inner-join, not-exists

I have a sql that is not very complex but sufficiently confusion that I question rather I have an equivalent or by coincident that the count are the same.

SQL1:

```
SELECT a, b
FROM table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT a, c
  FROM TABLE2
  WHERE table2.a != table1.a)
```

SQL2

```
SELECT table1.a, table1.b
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.a = table1.a
WHERE table2.a IS NULL
```

The count on the two are identical, but not sure if this is by chance, and I want to make sure the conversion do not change the original functionality.

Comment: Not sure I'm getting the functionality of SQL1. You want to get a, b from table1 where a is the only value of table2.a?

Comment: I think the point is to get rows from table1 where there is not a corresponding entry in table2.

Comment: @Dave Yes, I think that is the original intended purpose. But I am not 100% sure, and I am trying to optimize it so that it will run faster.

Comment: The way that the first query is written seems to be to get all rows from table1 such that no non-matching rows in table2 exist. And I think that would only work if **all** the rows in table2 matched exactly **one** value of table1.a

Comment: @Churk, you don't mention what RDBMS you're using. I tried both statements in Oracle and I found that the WHERE EXISTS version will use an index if there is one on table2 but the join condition with != (shown below) will not. In other words, you're better off with the NOT EXISTS, at least in Oracle, assuming an index. You certainly don't need "SELECT a,c" in the subquery, however; you can just use "SELECT 1" or "SELECT 'X'".

Comment: @DavidFaber I am using DB2, and yes, my attempt to optimize actually yield a very slight performance decrease. But the tool I am using to analyse the runtime and cost speaks differently. At low range of rows, the not exists does very well, using indexes. but at more than 10 mil rows, it start to run into issues of Cartesian scan and hash compare. While the left join I can be sure of which row I am indexing and which row to compare. And to be exact, the query is actually a lot more complex, this is just a very small portion of the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first query, as you have it, returns all rows of TABLE1 where `a` matches all values of `a` in TABLE2. Therefore, it will return zero rows, **unless there's a single not-null value for `a` in TABLE2**, and that value exists in TABLE1. In that case, it will return as many rows as there are in TABLE1 with that value of `a`.

The second query is completely different. It will simply returns all rows of TABLE1 where `a` does not exist in TABLE2.

So it's "***matches all***" (query 1) vs. "***does not match any***" (query 2). The fact that you are getting the same number of rows is pure coincidence.

Your queries would be equivalent if you changed `!=` for `=` in the first one, like this:

```
SELECT a, b
FROM table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT a, c
  FROM TABLE2
  WHERE table2.a = table1.a)
```

That gets you values of `a` in table1 that doesn't exist in table2. This is EXACTLY the same as:

```
SELECT table1.a, b
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.a = table1.a
WHERE table2.a IS NULL
```

As you have it though, they are NOT equivalent. You must change `!=` for `=` in the first one to make them so.

Comment: The first query can not change, it is what I am converting from. so in sort, the two queries are not equivalent, just by coincident that the count came back the same.

Comment: The first query is not valid syntax (hint: EXIST), nor is the second one (hint: `a` in the `SELECT` clause is ambiguous) and they are not equivalent either!

Comment: @onedaywhen I basically had to retype the queries, so forgive the spelling mistakes. But that is not what I had issues with nor is that the question.

Comment: @Churk, you are right. Please see if my edits answer your question now.

Comment: Thank, that is what I was afraid of, because it didn't make sense, but the count results of both are equal threw me off.

Answer (score 3):

That doesn't look the same - but it's close. Your LEFT JOIN syntax is the same as:

```
SELECT a, b
FROM table1
WHERE NOT EXIST(
  SELECT a, c
  FROM TABLE2
  WHERE table2.a = table1.a)
```

Note the "=" instead of "!=" though. Are you sure that's not what you have?

Your actual query translates to something like "where no non-matching rows exist", which would be odd, but could be expressed by changing the JOIN condition:

```
SELECT a, b
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.a != table1.a
WHERE table2.a IS NULL
```

Comment: The first sql is what I have and the second sql is what I can change. So what you are saying is on the join condition, I should use a != on the joining column, but doesn't that cause another problem itself?

Comment: @Churk: The only problem I see is that it's confusing as hell - but less so than the original query. It's an odd condition to check, and doesn't really fit well with (at least my) standard set thinking - but if you're 100% positive that's what you've got, I'd go with the LEFT JOIN and plenty of why-type comments.

Answer (score 2):

For the first query i.e.

```
SELECT a, b
FROM table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT a, c
  FROM TABLE2
  WHERE table2.a != table1.a)
```

This will return all rows when all the values of `a` in `table1` are the same one value and either all the rows in `table2` are the same one value as `table1` or `table2` is the empty set. Otherwise, the result will be the empty set.

The same cannot be same of your second query.

Comment: Thank you for further explaining, I can see what you mean now.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a, b, c , d
FROM table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM table2 nx
  WHERE nx.y = t1.a
  )
  ;
```

There is one big advantage of this ("correlated subquery") method:  table table2 is not visible from the outside query, and cannot pollute it, or confuse your thinking. The subquery just produces one bit of information: either it exists, or does not exist. *to be or not to be ...*.
In that respect, the LEFT JOIN idiom is nastier, since you'll have to check the `xxx IS NULL` condition *in the outer query*, while the xxx references the table2 from the inner query.

Technically, there is no difference.